# Limit textarea to text that "fits"

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textarea

I have a textarea with a variable-width font and I need to ensure the user cannot input more text than it "fits" on the textarea without scrolling.

Simply trapping keydown and `preventDefault()`'ing means I cannot cover the use-case where the user pastes things in the textarea.

Calculating the width of the text isn't helping me determine how much text *does* fit in that box.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do not use javascript at all. You can use css e.g. `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: You could always make an auto-expandable text area - that wouldn't scroll, is that an option? I could help you there.

Comment: That's not my issue, but instead that I **need** to prevent text inside from overflowing. As in, the very least I should know is how much text is overflowing from that fixed-size-in-px, variable-size-in-characters box and prevent it from ending up in the textarea's value

Comment: Hi i faced same issue and want to ask is there new solution?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind using jQuery, the solution is really simple. Firstly, save the current value of the textarea in a variable. Then listen to `input` event on the textarea, and check if it has a scrollbar by comparing `this.scrollHeight` and `this.clientHeight`. If so, change the textarea value to the previous value. In the end, assign the current textarea value to the `lastValue` variable.

See code snippet:

```js
var lastValue = $("textarea").val()
$("textarea").on("input", function(event) {
  if (this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight) {
    $("textarea").val(lastValue)
  }
  lastValue = $("textarea").val()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Pure JavaScript solution:

```
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea")
var lastValue = textarea.value
textarea.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  if (this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight) {
    textarea.value = lastValue
  }
  lastValue = textarea.value
})
```